# When I am using listagg in procedure I am getting plsql numeric or value error

Tags: sql, plsql

Ora-06502: pl/SQL: numeric or value error.

select listagg(listagg(l_comb,';') within group (order by rownum) as l_comb into out_output_string
From (select product_id|| ':' || rule_group as l_comb from dt1 ).
My expected output for example - 1234:12;456:23

Comment: I presume that the result is too long (exceeds 4000 characters).

Comment: I checked that too but the length is 589 only. Inside the block maximum I am getting 2500 only.

Comment: How is OUT_OUTPUT_STRING declared? What is its datatype and size?

Comment: Declared as out parameter varchar2

Comment: VARCHAR2 has to have **size**. I asked you both - datatype and size. You missed to reply to the 2nd part of my question.

Comment: create or replace procedure add_list( cust in varchar2,out_output_string out varchar2,out_product_count out number)

Comment: Didn't kept any size for out parameter

Comment: Aha, that's an OUT parameter. OK. What is then target variable's datatype and size? You're calling the procedure, and you're assigning OUT_PRODUCT_COUNT to *something* - I presume that's some local variable. How is it declared?

Comment: Out_product_count that is the count of product_id from the above query dt1 with clause table.but that is coming without error but the listagg is showing error and output is not displaying while running but we were able to get and see by calling the procedure/anonymous block.

Comment: Sorry, I meant to ask about OUT_OUTPUT_STRING - it is supposed to accept result of the LISTAGG, isn't it? Basically, it would be way simpler if you edited the original question (not via comments) and post the entire procedure code (note that piece of code you posted so far is invalid - you have two LISTAGGs) and the way you call it.

Comment: This looks like the same issue as [How to fix Character string buffer too small error in OUT variable in Stored Procedure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56920949/how-to-fix-character-string-buffer-too-small-error-in-out-variable-in-stored-pro). That is why @Littlefoot wants to know about the target variable that gets assigned the value of your parameter.

Answer (score 0):

If your out_output_string parameter is type **VARCHAR2** and it is used in a SQL statement, the parameter will return a string up to the length of
4000 characters (11g and earlier) or [MAX_STRING_SIZE](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/spmsu/enabling-the-new-extended-data-type-capability.html) (12c and above).

Your error is occurring because a local variable in a separate PL/SQL procedure is too small. See [How to fix Character string buffer too small error in OUT variable in Stored Procedure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56920949/how-to-fix-character-string-buffer-too-small-error-in-out-variable-in-stored-pro)

I would recommend adding an **EXCEPTION** block in the **ADD_LIST** procedure. Use [UTL_CALL_STACK](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/arpls/UTL_CALL_STACK.html) to trace the program flow. Follow the stack trace to find the variable that is sized too small.

### Sample package

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE test_pkg
AS
  pkg_ten_chars VARCHAR2(10); -- pkg_variable that is too small 
  PROCEDURE add_list(out_output_string OUT VARCHAR2);
  PROCEDURE add_list_passthrough(out_output_string2 OUT VARCHAR2);  
END test_pkg;

CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY test_pkg
AS

PROCEDURE add_list(out_output_string OUT VARCHAR2)
IS
BEGIN

  WITH dt1
  AS
  (select 1234 product_id, 12 rule_group from dual
   UNION
   select 456 product_id, 23 rule_group from dual
  )
  SELECT LISTAGG(product_id|| ':' || rule_group, ';') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY ROWNUM)
  INTO out_output_string -- return variable can be up to MAX_STRING_SIZE of SQL statement
  FROM dt1;

EXCEPTION 
  WHEN OTHERS THEN
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('[how code got here - ' || SQLERRM || ']');
    -- start at depth = 2 because depth = 1 will be the line below
    FOR d in 2 .. utl_call_stack.dynamic_depth() LOOP
        dbms_output.put_line('Depth: ' || d
                             || ', Procedure: ' || utl_call_stack.concatenate_subprogram(utl_call_stack.subprogram(d))
                             || ', Line: '|| to_char(utl_call_stack.unit_line(d))
                             );
    END LOOP;
END add_list;

PROCEDURE add_list_passthrough(out_output_string2 OUT VARCHAR2)
IS
BEGIN 
  add_list(test_pkg.pkg_ten_chars); -- (line=33) errors b/c package variable is too small
  out_output_string2 := test_pkg.pkg_ten_chars;
END add_list_passthrough;

END test_pkg;
```

Using an anonymous PL/SQL block to call the different procedures.

```
DECLARE
  l_local_max_chars VARCHAR2(4000); -- local variable of max characters
  l_local_ten_chars VARCHAR2(10);   -- local variable of ten characters
BEGIN
  test_pkg.add_list_passthrough(l_local_max_chars); -- (line=5) errors in add_list_passthrough
  test_pkg.add_list(l_local_max_chars);             -- OK
  test_pkg.add_list(l_local_ten_chars);             -- (line=7) errors b/c local variable too small
END;
```

### Results

```
[how code got here - ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error]
Depth: 2, Procedure: TEST_PKG.ADD_LIST_PASSTHROUGH, Line: 33
Depth: 3, Procedure: __anonymous_block, Line: 5
[how code got here - ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error]
Depth: 2, Procedure: __anonymous_block, Line: 7
```